# Add information to an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, file, addition

I've made a VBA macro that allows me to get information from a specific file from a folder.

The format of the name  is `Name_Timestamp.extension`
I get the TimeStamp.

What I need to do: add the Name file in `column  G`, the time stamp in `column  B` and a word in `column  J` to an Excel with headers.

Do you have any Idea on how I can do it ?

```
     
    Dim Chemin As String, Fichier As String, timeStamp As String
     
    'Définit le répertoire contenant les fichiers
    Chemin = "PATH"
    Fichier = Dir(Chemin & "*.*")
    timeStamp = Split(Fichier, "_")(2)
    timeStamp = Split(timeStamp, ".")(0)


    Do While Len(Fichier) > 0
        
        MsgBox (Fichier & "___" & timeStamp)
        Fichier = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this is really really basic, just Google for some beginner VBA tutorials

Comment: Is the name in column `G` supposed to be the file name or the file name with or without the timestamp, and/or with or without the file extension? What is the word in column `J` all about? Please do clarity.

Answer (score 0):

### Split by Timestamp

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitByTimeStamp()
     
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const aWord As String = "a word"
    Const TimeStampDelimiter As String = "_" ' don't use a dot ('.').
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim FileName As String: FileName = Dir(FolderPath & pSep & "*.*")
    Dim cRow As Long: cRow = FirstRow
    
    Dim sArr() As String
    Dim cString As String
    Dim NoStamp As String
    Dim TimeStamp As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        sArr = Split(FileName, TimeStampDelimiter)
        Select Case UBound(sArr)
        Case 0
            cString = sArr(0)
            NoStamp = Left(cString, InStrRev(cString, ".") - 1)
            TimeStamp = ""
        Case 1
            NoStamp = sArr(0)
            cString = sArr(1)
            TimeStamp = Left(cString, InStrRev(cString, ".") - 1)
        Case Else
            For n = 0 To UBound(sArr) - 1
                NoStamp = NoStamp & sArr(n) & TimeStampDelimiter
            Next n
            NoStamp = Left(NoStamp, Len(NoStamp) - Len(TimeStampDelimiter))
            cString = sArr(UBound(sArr))
            TimeStamp = Left(cString, InStrRev(cString, ".") - 1)
        End Select
        ws.Cells(cRow, "B").Value = TimeStamp
        ws.Cells(cRow, "G").Value = NoStamp
        ws.Cells(cRow, "J").Value = aWord
        cRow = cRow + 1
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Files Found: " & cRow - FirstRow, vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```